# How to hide subfolder of static pages in Wordpress using htaccess

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I need help please because I cannot find a solution for my problem.

I need to hide a subfolder in the url of my wordpress site.

I created a subfolder where I uploaded some static pages in php

Example: domain.com/subfolder/file.php

What I need is remove/hide "subfolder" to get the next:

domain.com/file.php

I tried many htaccess codes I found here but I always get a 404 error.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why don't you storage your static on / getting rid of the subfolder, I don't really know if what you want is possible but I wonder what is the problem with not creating a subfolder if then you want to use other path.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Castiblanco. Well, I have some folders and many files inside each one, so, I preffer to be organized and use folders instead of place all in the root.